# In java, how can i calculate distance between multiple latitude and longitude?

Tags: java

I am creating a project in which i'm using `Google direction API` to calculate distance between multiple latitude and longitude. But that is showing incorrect. I want to use `Java` for calculating the distance between multiple latitude and longitude.

Here is my java code

```
private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
  double theta = lon1 - lon2;
  double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit == 'K') {
    dist = dist * 1.609344;
  } else if (unit == 'N') {
    dist = dist * 0.8684;
    }
  return (dist);
}

private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? If Java, programmers exchange might help more

Comment: @WilliamIsted 
in java, i want to know.

Comment: Can you calculate the distance between two points correctly?  If yes, does "multiple" mean "iterating over pairs of points"?  If the answer to the first one is "no", I don't see how you can do the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exact, and Dutch, but I don't think it is hard to understand:

package nl.abz.testjaap;

```
public class Locatie {
  private static final double DOORSNEDE_AARDE = 40000.0;
  public final double latitude;
  public final double longitude;

  public Locatie(double latitude, double longitude) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if (latitude > 90 || latitude < -90) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("latitude moet tussen - 90 en 90 liggen, was "
              + latitude);
  }
  if (longitude < -360 || longitude > 360) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Longitude moet tussen -360 en 360 liggen was "
              + longitude);
  }
  this.latitude = latitude;
  this.longitude = longitude;
```

}

```
/**
 * Calculate the distance in KM
 * 
 * @param l2
 * @return
 */
public double afstandTot(Locatie l2) {
  double lon1 = longitude / 180 * Math.PI;
  double lon2 = l2.longitude / 180 * Math.PI;
  double lat1 = latitude / 180 * Math.PI;
  double lat2 = l2.latitude / 180 * Math.PI;
  double x1 = Math.cos(lon1) * Math.cos(lat1);
  double y1 = Math.sin(lon1) * Math.cos(lat1);
  double z1 = Math.sin(lat1);

  double x2 = Math.cos(lon2) * Math.cos(lat2);
  double y2 = Math.sin(lon2) * Math.cos(lat2);
  double z2 = Math.sin(lat2);

  double psi = Math.acos(x1 * x2 + y1 * y2 + z1 * z2);
  double afstand = DOORSNEDE_AARDE / (2 * Math.PI) * psi;
  return afstand;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

To calculate distance between 2 points you need to use [Haversine formula](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Java).

In java:

```
public class Haversine {

    public static final double R = 6372.8; // In kilometers

    // calculate distance with haversine formula
    public static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return R * c;
    }

    // example how to use
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(haversine(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40));
    }
}
```

Comment: same code i'm using but didn't get exact distance, same lat lng if i'm passing to the google map it is showing incorrect.

Comment: then show us your code to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
  double theta = lon1 - lon2;
  double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit == 'K') {
    dist = dist * 1.609344;
  } else if (unit == 'N') {
    dist = dist * 0.8684;
    }
  return (dist);
}

/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
/*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/
/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
/*::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :*/
/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
}
```